# I have a problem with a subtraction of a Quantity using an Object X from Array 1 and Object Y of Array 2

Tags: arrays, typescript

The function I use its OK but, when I try to do the subtraction both arrays gets subtracted

Variables:

```js
let data1 = [
  { ProductTotalId: 30, ProductId: 30, Quantity: 50 },
  { ProductTotalId: 31, ProductId: 29, Quantity: 20 },
  { ProductTotalId: 32, ProductId: 28, Quantity: 30 },
  { ProductTotalId: 33, ProductId: 27, Quantity: 30 },
];

let Remove = [
  { ProductTotalId: 30, ProductId: 30, Quantity: 2 },
  { ProductTotalId: 30, ProductId: 30, Quantity: 10 },
  { ProductTotalId: 31, ProductId: 29, Quantity: 3 },
  { ProductTotalId: 32, ProductId: 28, Quantity: 12 },
  { ProductTotalId: 32, ProductId: 28, Quantity: 2 },
  { ProductTotalId: 33, ProductId: 27, Quantity: 11 },
  { ProductTotalId: 33, ProductId: 27, Quantity: 5 },
]
let data2
```

function:

```js
data2 = data1;
for (let value of data2) {
  for (let data of Remove) {
    if (value.ProductId === data.ProductId) {
      value.Quantity = value.Quantity - data.Quantity;
    }
  }

}
console.log(data1);
console.log(data2);
```

The error is that data1 = data2, with Quantity Subtracted, what I need is that data2 gets subtracted and data 1 shouldn't suffer any changes.

link in Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-u8mzii

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data2 = data1` is just creating another reference for object. You are not making copy of the object `data1` here. So if you making changes to reference `data2` it will affect the object refered by `data1` (here same object).

to create copy of object use following

```js
data2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data1));
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-5hpvqc)

Comment: I would suggest `data2 = data1.map(r=>{ return {...r}})`

Comment: @Eldar that wouldn't work: you would have two arrays, but holding the same objects.

Comment: @Eldar As per my understanding this will work only for arrays. `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj);` is more generic and can clone almost every object. (of course without methods)

Comment: @JBNizet is right my first snippet was wrong. And for the `JSON.parse` @Plochie i think there are reasons behind that some libraries exposes methods named `deepClone`

Comment: @Eldar can u please elaborate. I know in this way you can only clone the state of object and not everything in it. But as far the data cloning goes, do u think this creates problem and in what scenarios?

Comment: Thanks so much, i need to learn more TypeScript :c, thanks for you're time.

Comment: @Plochie think that data had `Date` properties. What would have been then? Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-v9psc7)

Comment: @Eldar agreed. this is correct. As serialisation will only work for primitive types. But here I am considering the data which OP has provided. I think the conclusion should be if object has non primitive types with functions then one should use library like lodash (deepClone), but if its simple json then this should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is data structure.

`data2 = data1;` This piece of code does not create 2 arrays.

Data2 is also pointing on that was initially pointed by Data1. In order to have 2 arrays, you must create an array and insert all the content from array1.

You should instead do this:

```
const data2= Object.assign([], data1);
```

Now you will have a clone.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `data1` to suffer from changes in `data2`, you have to create a copy of `data1` as `data2`. You can use following method to copy `data1` into `data2`.

```
let data2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data1))
```

This would first stringify(JSON it) `data1`, then parse its result into `data2` so it would be identical to `data1` but not the same.